# How to get the glyphs of a pdf file using java/scala?

Tags: java, scala, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf file in devanagiri. Some of the glyphs are being mapped in an incorrect manner. I want to extract all these glyphs from a pdf file and map them to correct unicode. How do i extract the glyphs of a pdf file?

https://1drv.ms/b/s!AmHcFaD-gMGyhipy6feWmHK7Ea-P

Comment: I am quite sure that you won't find many people that willingly download an untrusted file you provide.

Comment: Also you could add your own conducted reasearch and results it yielded. What did you try so far? What have you ruled out as not possible for your use-case? What didn't work exactly the way you wanted it to? We are happy to help you when you get stuck but probably noone is going to do all of your work for you :)

Comment: *"I want to extract all these glyphs"* - what do you mean by *extracting those glyphs*? Do you want to get the glyph outlines from the font file?

Comment: A starting point could be DrawPrintTextLocations.java from the source code download, and PDFBox answers that mention "ToUnicode".

Comment: @mkl, well what i have is these information in this pdf: <0577> -> क, <0578>->ख.....<1b44>-ज्ञ.These characters are correctly mapped to proper unicode ids using toUnicode map i.i <0577>-><0915> nd so on. However after ज्ञ, the next character अ is mapped to glyph ID <0567> which is mapped to <0904> which isn't the proper unicode map for अ, then आ is mapped to अ and इ  to आ. I have used pdfbefugger to get this info. Pdfdebugger has used java objects to represent glyphs. I want to extract these glyphs. Can you help me?

Comment: So you essentially want the glyph IDs instead of the characters they are mapped to by **ToUnicode**? Or do you want the **ToUnicode** map of each respective font?

Comment: @mkl yeah, the glyph ids will do. Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The OP clarified in a comment that he essentially wants the glyph IDs instead of the characters they are mapped to by **ToUnicode**. As the font in question has an **Identity-H** encoding, the glyph IDs coincide with the character codes.*

The character codes of the text glyphs are contained in the `TextPosition` objects processed by the text stripper. Thus, you have to add your own code to the stripper in a method which still has these `TextPosition` objects.

The final method for which this is true is `writeString(String, List<TextPosition>)` which by default ignores the second parameter and calls `writeString(String)` with the first character.

You in contrast must not ignore the second parameter but inspect it, e.g. like this:

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        for (TextPosition textPosition : textPositions) {
            writeString(String.format("%s%s", textPosition.getUnicode(), Arrays.toString(textPosition.getCharacterCodes())));
        }
    }
};
//stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
String text = stripper.getText(document);

System.out.printf("\n*\n* singNepChar.pdf\n*\n%s\n", text);
```

*([ExtractCharacterCodes](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractCharacterCodes.java#L41) test `testExtractFromSingNepChar`)*

This example only outputs each extracted character alongside the character code it was extracted from. You can instead do any evaluation of the given data, e.g. a mapping to Unicode based on the character code and additional information you may have.

You actually have much more information at your hand, the `TextPosition` in particular also contains the font object (via `getFont`) of the text. As the character codes may differ from font to font, this information might become important to you.

In case of your sample document the output is

```
*
* singNepChar.pdf
*
क[1399] [3]ख[1400] [3]ग[1401] [3]घ[1402] [3]ङ[1403] [3]च[1404] [3]छ[1405] [3]ज[1406] [3]झ[1407] [3]ञ[1408] [3]ट[1409] [3]ठ[1410] [3]ड[1411] [3]ढ[1412] [3]ण[1413] [3]त[1414] [3]थ[1415] [3]द[1416] [3]ध[1417] [3]न[1418] [3]प[1420] [3]फ[1421] [3]ब[1422] [3]भ[1423] [3]म[1424] [3]य[1425] [3]र[1426] [3]ल[1428] [3]व[1431] [3]श[1432] [3]ष[1433] [3]स[1434] [3]ह[1435] [3]क्ष[6979] [3]त्र[7074] [3]ज्ञ[6980] [32]
ऄ[1383] [3]अ[1384] [3]आ[1385] [3]इ[1386] [3]ई[1387] [3]उ[1388] [3]ऊ[1389] [3]ए[1393] [3]ऐ[1394] [3] [3]ओ[1397] [3]औ[1398] [32]ऄ[1383]ं[1381] [3]ऄ[1383]ः[1382] [32]
 [32]
 [32]
 [32]
 [32]
 [32]
 [32]
 [32]
 [32]
```

(Beware, my outputs are decimal while the data in your comments are hexadecimal.)

Comment: in this pdf file i have a string "सुन" being separated as स[1434] , नु[1418]. I started making my own map of glyph ID to character but in this case, the ु's glyph ID is missing. It shuld be स[1434], न[1441],  ु[1418]. How do i get this?                                                                           https://1drv.ms/b/s!AmHcFaD-gMGyhkHr4PY6F4krYJ32

Comment: As you also posted this problem as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50664162/1729265), I replied [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50679508/1729265).